# How do I disable all mouse events on the map (click, hover, etc)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqvmap

I am wanting to use this product to display the US map with states selected already. I do not need any click functionality. I cannot for the life of me prevent the onRegionClick function from firing. I have tried using the ' event.preventDefault ' method, but it doesn't work. Can anybody help?

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({ 
  map: 'russia_en',
  // removed other declarations not needed in this example
  onRegionOver: function(event,code, region)
  {
    if (code)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  });
```

This prevents the mouseover event to do it's work on the map I loaded. If you add similar code for the other events you should be good.

Comment: This looks promising, I will try it tomorrow

Comment: It works for the event I mentioned, if it doesn't for others I can try some more fiddling :)

Comment: Oh, for some reason `onRegionClick` did not behave like the other events in my implementation, that's why I had to find a workaround eventually. `event.preventDefault();` wasn't doing anything

Comment: it depends where you put it of course, it can be very picky :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue recently and I ended up using a workaround.

In `onRegionClick: function(event, code, region) {...}` you could check if `code` is in the selected states array and use `$vmap.vectorMap('set', 'colors', '#selectedOrDeselected')` to set the state colors accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled to disable the click on regions, finally I used a simpler solution to disable the clicking on the map :

`$('#vmap').off('click');`